# How does one create a single atomic table from 3 different database tables

Tags: c#, linq

everyone. I am writing a simple database application in C# using EF6 and Sql compact. In my database I have 3 tables: Participants, SurveyItems, and Responses:

[image]

What my application requires is to draw from all 3 of these tables to create a 2D representation of the data such that: Each column represents one SurveyItem, each row represents 1 Participant, and each Cell represents one response (i.e. a participant's response to a survey item).

I have a LINQ query that pulls survey responses and groups them by participant:

```
var dataRows = Responses.Where(r => r.Participant.StudyID == XX)
               .GroupJoin(SurveyItems, 
                    r => r.ItemID,
                    s => s.ID,
                    (c, newRow) => c).GroupBy(p => p.Participant);
```

And I suppose I could simply iterate through the results of the query and construct the table that way, but that seems rather inelegant. I figure there must be a way to construct a query that will structure the data to fit my needs, but I can't seem to wrap by brain around it at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `StudyIdentifier` _and_ `StudyId`? (and you probably want a cross-ref table between `Participant` and `Study` anyways - what happens when people are part of multiple studies?)  What happens if multiple studies are supposed to use the same study?  Or just give the same one twice?  `ResponseValue` should **not** be a key (it's dependent data).  If you're ignoring the grouping given by `GroupJoin`, wouldn't you be better off with just `Join`? (yes, I know it gives rows with no responses)  Do you mean to lump all surveys together?

Comment: I see what you mean, and I did change the database to include a junction table. However, the StudyIdentifier column doesn't do what you might think. Participants receive an alphanumeric string to identify them upon entry into a research protocol, which is their study identifier. I changed the name of that column to be something less confusing.